# How to edit the variables while in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried many options but none of them seem to work

Im trying to change the:

> Player_System
>
> Player_Docked
>
> Player_Money [Not yet in use]

Thanks

I added a hyperlink to the code

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ohRLgLjIfo4oe0bU9PfTGmaQk4qRjaD2Qpzep0QDj9k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post your code here as formatted text, we're not going to check your Google Doc.

Comment: I gets all mixed up when I try to put it in the formatted code

Comment: Everyone else can manage to format code properly, you need to try harder, I'm afraid. Paste your code, select it all, and click the `{}` button. That should be all you need to do. If there's a *lot* of it, you should try and reduce it to a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the variables using global keyword.
Ex: global player_system = "Mars"

This value is reflected also in outside to the function

Edit : This code works fine

```
import time

global Player_System,Player_Docked;
Player_System="Earth"
Player_Docked = False
Player_Money = 0


# ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# Functions
# ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


def print_slow(str):
   for letter in str:
       print(letter)
       time.sleep(.3)


def LocalWarp(Player_System):
   print("Loading Map...")
   time.sleep(0.5)


   print("You are in the " + Player_System + " Orbit")
   time.sleep(0.6)
   print("Please make a selection:")
   print("1. Earth [Station in orbit]")
   print("2. Mars")

   # Insert here for more Orbit
   LocalWarpChoice = input("Make a selection now: ")
   if LocalWarpChoice == "1":
       if Player_System == "Earth":
           print("You are already here")
           time.sleep(0.7)
           main(Player_System,Player_Docked)
       else:
           print_slow("Warping..........................\n")

           Player_System == "Earth"
           print("We have arrived at " + Player_System)
           main(Player_System,Player_Docked)
   elif LocalWarpChoice == "2":
       if Player_System == "Mars":
           print("You are already here")
           time.sleep(0.7)
           main(Player_System,Player_Docked)
       else:

           print_slow("Warping.........................\n")


           Player_System = "Mars"
           print("We have arrived at " + Player_System)
           time.sleep(.4)
           main(Player_System,Player_Docked)


def Dock_Main(Player_System,Player_Docked):
   print("Welcome to " + Player_System + " Dock")
   print("Please do have a look around!!")
   time.sleep(0.3)
   print("Please make a selection:")
   time.sleep(0.7)
   print("1: Contracts")
   print("2: Buy some Food")
   print("3: Undock")
   dock_Choice = input("")
   if dock_Choice == "1":
       Contracts()
   elif dock_Choice == "2":
       Food_Buy()
   elif dock_Choice == "3":

       Player_Docked = False
       time.sleep(1)
       print("Undocking...")
       time.sleep(1)
       print("Undocked")
       time.sleep(0.5)
       main(Player_System,Player_Docked)


def Contracts():
   print("Todo")
   Dock_Main(Player_System,Player_Docked)


def Food_Buy():
   print("Todo")
   Dock_Main(Player_System,Player_Docked)


def Dock(Player_System,Player_Docked):
   if Player_System == "Earth":

       Player_Docked = True
       print("Docking at nearest station")
       time.sleep(0.3)
       print("Docked")
       time.sleep(0.3)
       Dock_Main(Player_System,Player_Docked)
   else:
       print("You are not in System with a Dock")
       main(Player_System,Player_Docked)


def main(Player_System,Player_Docked):

   print("Welcome")
   print("Please select a function")
   time.sleep(0.4)
   print("1: Warp")
   print("2: Dock")
   decision = input("")
   if decision == "1":

       LocalWarp(Player_System)
   elif decision == "2":
       Dock(Player_System,Player_Docked)


def bootfunc():
   print("Booting...")
   time.sleep(0.5)
   username = input("Enter a user name: ")
   print("Hello " + username)
   time.sleep(1)
   print("Loading Systems...")
   time.sleep(1)
   main(Player_System,Player_Docked)

print("Welcome to Space Game")
print("Press 1 to start a new Game")
new_or_load = input("")
if new_or_load == "1":
   bootfunc()

else:
   print("Error")
```

Comment: it comes up with this error

Comment: > Statement expected, found Py:EQEQ

Comment: Check out the code....It works fine now